# Fragment and hash in url link is hidden after refresh in angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing

I am working on angular2, when I have a fragment in the url for example
http://www.123.com#test => then I scroll to view and this is working perfect.
But when I do a refresh of the page, the #test is hidden and the tree.fragment become null.

I dont know why, please could you help me?